# How to write a file on a particular folder on google colab using Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I tried this but it gives me a syntax error.
Here 'win' is the folder and dosa_bce_win.py is the code file I want to write inside this folder.

```
!mkdir win 
%%writefile dosa_bce_win.py
```

Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so now I got the answer:

```
%%writefile ./win/dosa_bce_win.py
print("Hello")
```